# Listview items are not displayed after Button

Tags: android

I have added my code below. Listview items are not displayed after the Sync Button. I am using RelativeLayout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_sync"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_sync" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/company_factory_truck_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_sync"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    >

</ListView>
```

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>

Comment: are you sure that you're initializing the listview? Or are you trying to prompt initializing with the button?

Comment: I am initializaing listview and button separately.

Answer (score 0):

This code displays both button and listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_sync" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/company_factory_truck_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_sync"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

[This pic shows the output][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yaTb.png
```